# salesforce account address information required

Tags: validation, salesforce2salesforce, sales-cloud

i have an account and the all Shipping and Billing address are required and as long as they are standard fields they should have validation rule to complete the job i don know how to make it possible as am new at salesforce technology can any on help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did something similar to this. I have required both Shipping State and Billing country in my Org, you can use similar rules to ensure all address data is required. 
For Billing County my validation rule looks like:

```
ISBLANK(BillingCountry)
```

For Shipping State:

```
ISBLANK(ShippingState)
```

Just go to Setup->App Setup->Accounts->Validation Rules -> New

To set them up.

**Note:** My Org has enabled the 2013 Beta State & Country Pick lists - not sure if this is relevant, but in case your having issues with the above validation rules there may be a correlation.

Comment: Since you have State and Country Picklists enabled, I'd suggest updating your validation rules to check ISPICKVAL(BillingCountryCode, ''). You will also need to make sure every country enabled in your org has visible states. The rules you have should continue to work, but it can get dicey if you have many triggers/workflow rule updates operating on the state and country fields.

Comment: To clarify I have State and Country Pick lists beta option available, however have yet to implement it. Going through the initial scan of the org showed many areas that were to be affected. I hope to get to the actual implementation of state and country soon. At that time I'll look to do exactly as you mentioned. The list of affected fields, Apex, and validation rules are quite overwhelming so I'm trying to set up a plan of attack :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a validation rules for the Account , navigate

setup->Customize-> Account -> Validation Rules

we can create validation rules for all fields even std fields, for billing information and shipping information